# ReactJS: Create isolated component with own css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom, material-ui

I'm trying to develop a library of reactjs components in order to be reusable by different projects.

This components besides the functionality itself, must have a theme with different css styles.

I could write a css file, but then I must import the css in every project I will use any of that components. I need to set the style of this components inside itself, so when I import it in other project, I will looks exactly as I expect.

Is there any ReactJS library (or plugin perhaps?) to compile this styles inside the component or maybe apply a style on the `componentDidMount`?

### EDIT

I forgot to add that I'm using [MaterialUI](http://www.material-ui.com/). which is a framework that implements Material Design for React.

It provides different components which it own styles, and I can modify some of them, but not all.

Since Material UI create a big HTML I cannot add inline styles, that's why I need to add a selector to apply styles from React directly

Meterial UI provides something like that, so I guess is possible. This is how I configure in Material UI

```
const muiTheme = getMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    textColor: cyan500,
  },
  appBar: {
    height: 50,
  },
});
```

Sadly only some styles are supported by this, and not all I need

Comment: what's wrong with inline styles?

Comment: sorry, forgot that part. I'm using materialUI (http://www.material-ui.com/) for some of that elements, which has it own stylesheets and full HTML rendered inside that library. I can add a class or inline-style to the main container of that compoents, but I cannot go deeper with the inline styles

Comment: so you absolutely need to somehow import css FILES into your component is what you're saying?

Comment: Yes import css in the component. Or maybe apply style some how as jquery does `$('selector').css({...})` is there anything like that for React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use webpack for your transpiling, you can create a separate stylesheet for the component and then import it.

Example:

```
import './componentStyle.css';
```

Then setup your component style in that CSS. The component would need both the jsx and css files each time you use them in different projects, but you can easily customize the css for each project if you need, and you can use css classes instead of inline styles.

Your webpack.config.js would need to have this:

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'}
  ]
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't isolate the CSS. It applies everywhere unless you use some sort of custom naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

If you created application with `npx create-react-app` then

1. Import your styles from `*.module.css` file. Example: `import styles from './component.module.css'` with content `.ssss { color: red }`
2. Apply your style using `{styles.ssss}`. Example: `<div className={styles.ssss}>`

Answer (score 0):

MaterialUI now includes [CSS-in-JS docs](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/) functionality that will allow you to do just what you're asking.

you probably want to do something like what they [suggest](https://material-ui.com/css-in-js/basics/#higher-order-component-api) and make use of their HOC API:

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const styles = {
  root: {
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 3,
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(255, 105, 135, .3)',
    color: 'white',
    height: 48,
    padding: '0 30px',
  },
};

function HigherOrderComponent(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return <Button className={classes.root}>Higher-order component</Button>;
}

HigherOrderComponent.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(HigherOrderComponent);
```